# I'm having problem with pushup, benchpress at 3rd day at gym

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, workout

It's been 3 days since i joined gym, i'm a rookie.
First 2 days are fine I was able to do everything i.e. pushup, benchpress, pulldown, etc. But at 3rd day i,m not able to do even 1 pushup or benchpress.
I want to know why, where is the problem?

Comment: So you havent rested / let your muscles recover from your past 2 days of exercise?

Comment: This has been unimproved, and without more detail we are simply guessing as to where/what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is over-exercising.

"Working out" helps to develop the muscles and fitness by stressing the body.  The body responds by gradually adapting.

If you've never run before, and you try to run a marathon, you will get exhausted, your legs will cramp up, your feet will blister, ankles and knees will swell, etc.

That's because you're body is not prepared to run a marathon.

If you are doing pushups, benchpress, etc, you are similarly stressing those muscle groups.  When your body adapts to the stress/mild injury that workouts put on those muscles, it grows more muscle of different types of cells, which will allow you to do more reps, and more weights, and over time, your recovery time from the workouts will decrease, as well, since your body is acclimated to regular stressing of those groups, as well.

When you first start out, it's pretty normal that, after the first day of bench pressing or squats, you feel fairly sore and more easily fatigued, but that ***second*** day, rigor mortis sets in.

Your muscles need to rest and recover.  You also might need to start with lighter weights and/or less reps and sets.  Gradually increase over time as your body adapts.

Quite simply, the muscles are broken down, sore, swollen and inflamed and are unable to work, because they have been, temporarily, "damaged" by the exercise.  Ease up and recover.

If you really, really are jazzed about going to the gym and have boundless enthusiasm, then split your muscle groups up and alternate for each time at the gym.  You don't need to go every day, but if you split it up, then probably at least four times a week, total.  One example -

Day One - Chest/back/shoulders

Day Two - Biceps, triceps, quadriceps, hamstrings, calves (arms and legs)

Both days - Aerobic work like stationary bike, elliptical, stairmaster, jogging, treadmill, rowing machine, swimming, jogging or sports. Do it after your weight workout, not before, and it can be fairly light when done along with resistance training... half an hour or so.  On days when you don't go to the gym, maybe incorporate a little longer aerobic work.

Both days - Core

Comment: Over training is a long term (chronic) condition. Anything in 2 days is going to be acute (Short term). I'd also be interested in an explanation of the "more muscle of different types of cells" statement.

Comment: @JohnP - the muscles have received more (aka "over") intentional exercise (aka training) than they can handle. They are over-trained.  Saying something is overtrained is not the same as talking about over-training ***syndrome***. - "The dictionary states, 'Overtraining is a common problem in weight training, but it can also be experienced by runners and other athletes. It occurs when the volume and intensity of the exercise exceeds an individual's recovery capacity. They cease making progress, and can even begin to lose strength and fitness.'" - Nothing about it having to be long-term/chronic.

Comment: That also describes, exactly, what the OP describes in the question. https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/fawnia33.htm

Comment: If you read the entire article, you get to the point where it says "Fast forward 6 months and Jennifer is not feeling so hot". Over training is a chronic condition. Overdoing it is not the same as over training.

Comment: @JohnP - "overdoing it" is too general a term. If I walk around at the mall, and then drive four hours to visit family, I can be overdoing it.  If I eat too much at the pizza buffet I'm overdoing it.  This is the result of doing more training and exercise that his body is ready for. I don't want to lose that context.  Maybe "overtaxing" or even "over-exercising" might be be better. Edit made.

Comment: Rigor mortis meaning.... the stage of death when the muscles start to stiffen and decompose?

Comment: @DeeV - yes.... obviously an exaggerated (hopefully humorous) description of the stiffness that hits after the first workouts (either ever or after a long time off).